# Pass value/parameters in scripts Ajax load page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parameters

I load with jQuery Ajax another page who contains a script tag. How can I pass variable/parameters from the original page to the script tag of the page who is loaded ?

Scripts :

Page 1

```
  <script>
    $(function(){

      $('#button').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url: "test.html",
              success: function(retour){
                $("#content").html(retour);
              }
          });
          return false;
      });

    });
  </script>
```

Page 2 (who is loaded) :

```
  <script>
    $(function(){

      var Data = 'Data from origin page !';

    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are both static pages? Then you should do this:

```
window.DataFor2ndPage = {};
```

2nd page:

```
<script>
$(function(){

  var Data = DataFor2ndPage;

});
</script>
```

Comment: @Yago31 <script> var a = 5 </script> is the same as <script> window.a = 5 </script> see this to better understand: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable